# libopencv_hal.a doesn't exist error when trying to install iai_kinect2

Tags: opencv, ros, ubuntu-15.04, catkin

I'm trying to install iai_kinect2 package on ROS inside catkin_ws on ubuntu 15.04.

When I `make` `catkin_make`, I encounter the following error:

```
CMake Error at /usr/local/share/OpenCV/OpenCVModules.cmake:117 (message):
  The imported target "opencv_hal" references the file

     "/usr/local/lib/libopencv_hal.a"

  but this file does not exist.  Possible reasons include:

  * The file was deleted, renamed, or moved to another location.

  * An install or uninstall procedure did not complete successfully.

  * The installation package was faulty and contained

     "/usr/local/share/OpenCV/OpenCVModules.cmake"

  but not all the files it references.

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/local/share/OpenCV/OpenCVConfig.cmake:86 (include)
  vision_opencv/image_geometry/CMakeLists.txt:5 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/satellite/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/satellite/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Invoking "cmake" failed
```

How can I fix this error?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, you try build opencv via rpmbuild? For me solution was a change hal module type to shared in opencv/modules/hal/CMakeLists.txt

set(OPENCV_MODULE_TYPE SHARED)